# How do horizontally align text next to an image with CSS

Tags: html, css

[image]

How do I vertically align text next to an image with CSS like attached screnshot.

Ex : I had  attached screnshot with this post .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Float the image left and put `overflow:hidden` on the text to prevent it from going under the image.

Comment: This solution will cutoff the text if the person increases there text size.

Comment: @NeilMasters it's only cutoff the text when the height is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

A simple float usually does the trick:

```
img {
    float: left;
}

p {
    float: left;
}
```

This makes the text adapt to the image. If the text is longer than the image's height, it will wrap under it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS style for the image

```
clear:both
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p><img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" style="float:left;padding-right:12px" width="280" />Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
<br style="clear:both" />
<p>It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
```

Test this.